# Indexing(subsetting) the matrix using apply type functions?

Tags: r, apply, lapply

I want to separate each row from a matrix and apply a function which takes two arguments.
For example consider the following code

```
Mat <- matrix(1:100,nrow=10)

    for(i in 1:nrow(Mat)){
    x <- Mat[i,]
    y <- Mat[-i,]
    function(x,y)
    }
```

This loop is running very slowly. I want to avoid this `for` loop and use some kind apply functions. I am not able to subset the matrix using these functions. I tried to make list of all rows and subsetted matrices to use `Map` or `mapply` but that list becomes too large to fit in the memory. is it possible to do in other way? Please help.

**EDIT**
This is the function I am running iside the loop

```
fun <- function(x,y){
      y <- y[,!is.na(x)]
      x <- x[!is.na(x)]
      if(length(x) > 10){
            y <- y[apply(y,1,function(x){!TRUE %in% is.na(x)}),]
            testMatrix <- matrix(0,nrow=2,ncol=2)
            testMatrix[1,1] <- sum(x)
            testMatrix[1,2] <- length(x)
            testMatrix[2,1] <- sum(apply(y,1,sum))
            testMatrix[2,2] <- sum(apply(y,1,length))
            P_Value <- chisq.test(testMatrix)$p.value
      }
      else{
            P_Value <- NULL
      }
      return(P_Value)
}
```

Comment: It is probably not the loop itself that is particularly slow in this case, but rather one of two things.  1) Subsetting the matrix. 2) Your function. What are you really trying to do?

Comment: I am just summing the values and performing chisquare test in the function. Anyways I want to do that without a for loop is it possible?

Comment: It is possible. It won't necessarily be much faster, unless you take advantage of the specific structure of your function (which is why @Andrie was asking you). For example you can write `lapply(1:nrow(Mat), function(i) f(Mat[i,], Mat[-i,]))` (where `f` is your function in your `for` loop). It won't be fast just because you avoid writing the word `for`. You need to show show your actual `f` function if you want to get help.

Comment: Edited the question with the function i am running. Thanks.

Comment: I tested your code on a matrix of 100 x 1000 and the code runs in less than a second. What does your real data look like?

Comment: Dimensions of my matrix are 28,142 x 32. I am running that loop 28,142 times!!. That is the problem. It is taking ~2 hours to complete.